# Python 3 Largest to smallest loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am attempting to write a program that asks a user to enter a series of numbers. Once the numbers are entered they should be ordered from largest to smallest. Here is what I have so far, I am having a little trouble figuring out how I can order the numbers the user has put in. I'm pretty sure a do-while loop should be used, and I am trying to figure out how to implement it. Also the user should enter -99 to end the series of numbers.

```
   //Define main function
    def main():
        numbers()
        loop()


    //Get user input
    def numbers():
        a=input()
        b=input()
        c=input()
        d=input()
        e=input()
        number1=int(a)
        number2=int(b)
        number3=int(c)
        number4=int(d)
        number5=int(e)

    //Define loop function
    def loop():

    //Call main function
    main()
```

Comment: [Arrays](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) will certainly tickle your pickle.

Comment: @DesertIvy arrays are overkill for beginners, just use an ordinary list!

Comment: You can use [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) on a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). You don't want write your own loop to sort... others have already done the work for you.

Comment: Or you can use the `.sort` method on a list :)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm a "go big or go home" kinda guy ;)

Comment: I strongly recommend that you follow a tutorial, even a short one. At this stage, you're not even using the correct comment syntax. Afterwards, return to this project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
numbers = []
while True:
    number = int(input('Give me a number: '))
    if number == -99: break
    numbers.append(number)
for number in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
    print(number)
```

Comment: sorted(numbers, reverse=True)

Comment: `sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: -x)`

Comment: The amount of numbers is not known before. The program should continue till the user hits -99, so a for-loop is not the best way.

Comment: @BasSwinckels True, I've just read the -99 part and changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: `reverse=True` is the preferred way of doing this; but even if you didn't do that, `lambda x: -x` is actually already built in, as `operator.neg` or just `int.__neg__` since you are converting each item to an int.  You don't always need a `lambda`

Answer (score -1):

I perhaps shouldn't be helping you to this extent, learning and all, but I am utterly unable to resist posting this oneliner:

```
def thingy():
    return sorted(map(int, iter(raw_input, '-99')), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Ooo ... the rarely seen 2 argument form of `iter`.  It is an elusive beast! :)

Comment: Please don't scare the new kids away ;).

Comment: If he wanted to scare the OP away, he'd use `thingy = lambda: reversed(sorted(map(int, iter(raw_input, '-99')))`. :)

Comment: @chepner: `reversed(sorted(...))` is just a slower, more memory consuming version of `sorted(..., reverse=True)`,  so don't do it.

Comment: I know; I was just trying to make the LISP-iest looking line I could.